# Git bash does not show real time updates for python

Tags: python, django, git, git-bash

My Git bash does not show real-time outputs for Python. For example, if I try to print "Loading", then make an HTTP request, and then print out something again, my git bash shows everything all at once.

I was trying to start Django runserver, and here's what I got:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
```

It kept showing this for some time, so I decided to re-run the command. When I pressed `CTRL + C`, I got this:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations 
for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
October 03, 2020 - 23:08:15
Django version 3.1.2, using settings 'first_django_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

This means the server actually started, but the bash did not show anything. How do I fix this?

**Edit:**
Since many of you have been asking for a sample file, here is a file I created to demonstrate the problem:

```
import time

print('#1 Statement 1')
time.sleep(10)

print('#2 Statement 2')
time.sleep(10)

print('#3 Statement 3')
```

An ideal output for this file should be that #1 shows immediately, then after 10s, #2 shows, then 10s later, #3 shows and the execution is completed.

However, in my bash, I do not get any output for 29s. At 30th second, I get all the three statements as output at once, and execution stops.

In the Django example as well, while the server was running, I did not see anything in the bash, but as soon as I pressed `CTRL + C`, the execution got interrupted, and I got the output from 'Performing system . . .' till end.

I hope it was clear what my problem is. Thank you.

Comment: show us your `print` code section

Comment: That is just an example I used to explain my problem. It does not happen specifically to any one file, but it happens to all python files.

Comment: Please post at least 1 python file that exhibits this behavior, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: I have tried to explain the issue a bit more. Please tell me if you understand my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a python script? Try flushing after using print and it should work.

```
print("hello")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: I have edited the question and tried to elaborate the problem with an example. Please try to help me out once more. Thank you.

Comment: Sure.... same diagnosis and treatment: try flushing after every `print()` call.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP and this workaround fixed it, but I'm still interested in why git bash won't spit out real time print statements unless you flush.. If I use anaconda prompt on the same python code (without flush statements), I get real time updates. Any ideas why anaconda prompt is working differently than git bash? If I'm running someone else's code, I don't want to have to go in an surgically add `sys.stdout.flush()`'s after every `print()`.

Comment: Sounds like a good (different) question to bring up.